# Changing copy-path button in atom text editor for use in cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, statusbar, atom-editor

I recently started coding in python and have been using atom as a text editor and cygwin to run the python code on Windows 10. Atom has this great feature where you can click on the files name in the status bar at the very bottom left and the path will be copied.

However, this path does not work in cygwin. For instance, atom would copy "C:\python\lab2_1.py" but what you need to write into cygwin is "python /cygdrive/c/python/lab2_1.py". So, I am wondering how you can change the output of the status bar copy button to accomodate this. Thank you!

Comment: There is a specific reason for using Cygwin? It's way better to have native Windows installation of Python, especially with the use of [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

Comment: My programming teacher specifically wants us to use cygwin as we will be working with c later on. I would have used IDLE otherwise :P

Comment: To change that behavior you have to dig into the atom's status-bar module, and override the function that retrieve the full-path of a file. To do that press `Ctrl+Alt+I` and you'll see the debugger. Go to `Sources`, on the right: open the list `Event Listener Breakpoints` and check `Mouse -> click`. Now Atom will break execution next time you click on the filename in the status bar.

Comment: Ok I have managed to find the place where it copies to clipboard and I know the syntax to modify it to however it will not let me save the edited version in that window, is there any way to do this?